# Angular2 template trying to render value before value returned from http.get

Tags: rest, angular, observable

I have an angular2 project as follows:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "self-assessment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings" : "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss": "^5.0.13",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.3",
    "precss": "^1.3.0",
    "typings":"^0.6.8",
    "tsd": "^0.6.5-beta"
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AssessmentListComponent} from "./assessment-list.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import {ApiService} from "../services/api.service";
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {AssessmentComponent} from "./assessment.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/app.component.html',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ],
    providers: [
        ApiService,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/assessments', name: 'Assessments', component: AssessmentListComponent},
    {path: '/assessment/:id', name: 'Assessment', component: AssessmentComponent},

])
export class AppComponent {

    title = "Welcome to Self-Assessment"

}
```

**assessment.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {AssessmentModel} from '../models/assessment.model';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {ApiService} from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'assessment-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/assessment.component.html',
})
export class AssessmentComponent implements OnInit{
    assessment: AssessmentModel;
    errorMessage: any;

    constructor(
        private _apiService: ApiService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams
    ) {}


    ngOnInit():any {
        let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
        this.getAssessment(id);
    }

    private getAssessment(id: number) {
        this._apiService.getAssessment(id)
            .subscribe(
                assessment => this.assessment = assessment,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

    goBack() {
        console.log(this.assessment);
    }
}
```

**api.service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    private _baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/';

    getAssessments() {
        return this.getObjectList('assessments', 'json');
    }

    getAssessment(id: number) {
        return this.getObject('assessments', id, 'json');
    }

    getObjectList(listName:string, listExtension: string) {

        var url =  this._baseApiUrl + listName + '.' + listExtension;

        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getObject(objectName:string, objectId:number, objectExtension: string) {

        var url =  this._baseApiUrl + objectName + '/' + objectId + '.' + objectExtension;

        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

and finally 
**assessment.component.html:**

```
<h3>{{ assessment.id }}</h3>
<button (click)="goBack()">Go Back 2</button>
```

When the page is called with the url: http://localhost:3000/assessment/4 it makes the appropriate calls to the back-end **twice** and generates the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in [{{ assessment.id }} in AssessmentComponent@0:4]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_AssessmentComponent_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_AssessmentComponent:30:28)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8116:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8099:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8184:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8103:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8178:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8100:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8184:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8103:12)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8088:12)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1206(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12591NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13635collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13539Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247NgZone._notifyOnTurnDone @ angular2.dev.js:13450(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13565zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
```

So it appears as though the {{ assessment.id }} is trying to render before the object is returned from the back-end.  If I then click the "Go Back 2" button it will console log the object appropriately:

```
{"id":4,"title":"Assessment Title here!","description":"Here is a description","questions":["http://localhost:8000/questions/1.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/2.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/3.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/4.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/5.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/6.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/7.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/8.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/9.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/10.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/11.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/12.json","http://localhost:8000/questions/13.json"],"responses":[]}
```

"Interestingly" I'm not seeing problems in other places in the application (ie. can load and display assessment-lists just fine, etc).  Also, I'm having the exact same problem in an Ionic2 app I was working with last night as a learning project.

Have googled my butt off, hopefully somebody knows the answer to this riddle.

Thanks!

Comment: Try ``{{ assessment?.id }}`` -- [Elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators).  You likely don't have the issue with lists because `NgFor` handles the undefined or empty array case for you.  Then when the data comes in, the `NgFor` is re-evaluated.

Comment: That does work, thank you.  Is that a 'right' way to solve it or is there a more appropriate solution?  It seems odd that wouldn't be mentioned in any of the tutorials and such I've looked at (that I've noticed anyway).  Thanks @MarkRajcok!

Comment: See my answer.  Many tutorials like to show examples with lists, which is probably why the Elvis operator is often unknown to developers learning Angular.  (This question comes up often on SO.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options:

1. use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) (formerly called the Elvis operator), `{{ assessment?.id }}`, which guards against null and undefined values
2. use NgIf, `<h3 *ngIf="assessment">{{assessment.id}}</h3>`, which is more appropriate if you don't want elements added to the DOM until the data is available/populated

You likely don't have the issue with lists because NgFor handles the undefined, null or empty array case for you. Then when the data comes in, NgFor is re-evaluated.

Comment: I've been coding for 20 years and never ran across the Elvis operator until now, cool thanks.

Comment: @EricSoyke, they now call it the "safe navigation operator".